# mktextfm ecss0400 fails

Tags: beamer, fonts, errors, installing-fonts

I updated my texlive 2017 installation on my Linux Mint 17.2 machine and since then I can't compile this minimal (not) working example. A complete reinstall (complete version) of texlive didn't change the error.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\begin{document}    
\frame{
    Hello World!
}    
\end{document}
```

---

The pdf is created and seems fine, but using METAFONT with ecss0400 fails. Changing the documentclass to scrartcl results in no error.

If I compile this MWE with pdflatex, it invokes something with ecss0400 and that fails.

---

```
Prozess gestartet: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "beispiel".tex    
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecss0400    
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecss0400
```

---

```
! Font T1/cmss/m/n/4=ecss0400 at 4.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.12 }

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
```

---

Two additional log files are created. first the missfont.log file contains several lines of "mktextfm ecss0400".

The other file is called "ecss0400.log" and is very long, so i will only post some sections. It starts with

```
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded base=mf 2017.7.28)  28 JUL 2017 11:23
**\mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecss0400
(/home/ME/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/ecss0400.mf
(/localhdd/ME/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/exbase.mf)
(/localhdd/ME/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/ecss.mf
(/localhdd/ME/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/exroman.mf
 Ok
(/localhdd/ME/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/exaccess.mf
 Ok)
(/localhdd/ME/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/expseudo.mf
 Ok)
(/localhdd/ME/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/exruwest.mf
 Ok [192] [193] [194] [195] [196] [197] [198] [199] [200] [201] [202] [203]
[204] [205] [206] [207] [208] [209] [210] [211] [212] [213] [214] [215]
[216] [217] [218] [219] [220] [221] [222] [223])
(/localhdd/ME/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/exrlwest.mf
 Ok [224] [225] [226] [227] [228] [229] [230] [231] [232] [233] [234] [235]
[236] [237] [238] [239] [240] [241] [242] [243] [244] [245] [246] [247]
[248] [249] [250] [251] [252]
> 0 NNE 1 NNW WNW 2 (WSW) SSW 3 (SSE ESE) ENE NNE ENE ESE SSE SSW 4 5 WSW 0 (WN
W NNW)
! Strange path (turning number is zero).
<to be read again> 
                   ;
<for(%CAPSULE10676)> ...oke.z3e---z5e...{left}z6e;
                                                  pickup.fine.nib;pos6'(bot_...
l.1012 repeat_once
                  ;
The path doesn't have a counterclockwise orientation,
so I'll probably have trouble drawing it.
(See Chapter 27 of The METAFONTbook for more help.)
```

There are several errors like

```
[184]
! Square root of -1.16454 has been replaced by 0.
diag_ratio->...((EXPR2)*((EXPR5)++(EXPR4)*sqrt.a_)
                                                  -b_*(EXPR5))/a_/(EXPR4)end...
<for(1)> ...stem-tiny,y2-y3,x2r-x3l-slant*(y2-y3))
                                                  ;penpos1(alpha*(z_stem-tin...
l.1025 repeat_once
                  ;
Since I don't take square roots of negative numbers,
I'm zeroing this one. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

But it ends with

```
Font metrics written on ecss0400.tfm.
Output written on ecss0400.600gf (256 characters, 20732 bytes).
```

I'm currently assuming that there are errors in the font files provides by texlive. So is there anything I can do?

If I compile with lualatex everything works.

Comment: I already reported this to the beamer issue tracker: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/408. The code has already been fixed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `beamer` class, more precisely `beamerbasefont.sty`, has its own `\DeclareFontShape` for the Computer Modern/European Modern fonts.

The declarations are disputable, as the standard don't dare to choose fonts with design size below 5pt (below this threshold fonts are scaled). Compare with `fix-cm.sty` that does

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmss}{m}{n}{
        <-9>    ecss0800
        <9-10>  ecss0900
        <10-12> ecss1000
        <12-17> ecss1200
        <17->   ecss1728
      }{}
```

whereas `beamerbasefont.sty` has

```
\def\EC@family#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \DeclareFontShape{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  {<3><4><5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4>%
   <17.28><20.74><24.88><29.86><35.83><42.99><51.59>genb*#5}{}}

\EC@family{T1}{cmss}{m}{n}{ecss}
```

which is the culprit: when `\Tiny` is processed, which chooses a base font size of 4pt, TeX needs to generate `ecss0400`, which is not a tested design size and, indeed, its creation fails.

The package `beamerfontsize.sty` should be fixed *not* to use such small design sizes and to use instead `fix-cm.sty`.

Workaround: `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the workaround.

I can confirm that `\usepackage{lmodern}` is solving the problem.

Comment: I find that ``\usepackage{lmodern}`` must be placed before ``\usepackage{bm}``, if you're using it.

Answer (score -1):

The first question is, why on earth does this seemingly innocent file calls for a font ecss0400 which is at 4pt design size?

Unfortunately, at such a small size the METAFONT sources for the ec fonts aren't tested to work, and errors are expected to be present. This is a feature of the fonts, not a bug.

Comment: The `beamer` class defines `\Tiny` and `\TINY` to choose base font size 4pt and 3pt respectively. Whether this is sensible is a question for the author of the class.

Comment: Moreover `beamerbasefont.sty` does its own `\DeclareFontShape` commands, in a *very* wrong way.